# Pass a form field value to server in checkout page

Tags: payment, payment-methods, onestepcheckout

I am using the onestepcheckout extension as the store checkout.

One payment method allows customers to pay in payments.

The form collect the payments value using the following select field:

```
<select id="paymentsno" name="payment[additional_information][payments]" style="width: 263px;" class="selectboxit-hide-it">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

I am expecting to get this value in the payment method model:

```
$payment = $order->getPayment();
$paymentAdditional = $payment->getAdditionalInformation();
$payments = $paymentAdditional->getPayments();
```

I am able to retrieve a value **but it is always the default value of the select e.g. 1**

Any idea why?

Comment: I would assume, that the extension extends the functionality of `opcheckout.js`, and this is not working with the onestepcheckout extension.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Idev, the company behind OST? They might be familiar with the issue and have a fix ready to go

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module. Please contact the developer directly for support.